# Smaller variation between times of different days

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation, pseudocode

I have working on a algorithm that select a set of date/time objects with a certain characteristic, but with no success.

The data to be used are **in a list of lists of date/time objects**,
e.g.:

> lstDays[i][j],
>  i <= day chooser,
>   j <= time chooser

What is the problem? I need a set of **nearest date/time objects**. Each time of this set **must come from different days**.

For example: [2012-09-09 12:00,2012-09-10 12:00, 2012-09-11 12:00]

This example of a set of date/time objects is the best example because it minimize to zero.

**Important**

> *Trying to contextualize this: I want to observe if a phenomenon occurs at the same time in differents days. If not, I want to evaluate if distance between the hours is reasonable for my study.*

I would like a **generic algorithm** to any number of days and time. This algorithm should return all set of datetime objects and its time distance:

> [2012-09-09 12:00,2012-09-10 12:00, 2012-09-11 12:00], 0
>   [2012-09-09 13:00,2012-09-10 13:00, 2012-09-11 13:05], 5

and so on.

***::** "0", because the diff between all times on the first line from datetime objects is zero seconds.*
***::*** "5", because the diff between all times on the second line from datetime objects is five seconds.

Edit: Code here

```
for i in range(len(lstDays)):
    for j in range(len(lstDays[i])):
        print lstDays[i][j]
```

Output:

> 2013-07-18 11:16:00
>   2013-07-18 12:02:00
>   2013-07-18 12:39:00
>   2013-07-18 13:14:00
>   2013-07-18 13:50:00
>   2013-07-19 11:30:00
>   2013-07-19 12:00:00
>   2013-07-19 12:46:00
>   2013-07-19 13:19:00
>   2013-07-22 11:36:00
>   2013-07-22 12:21:00
>   2013-07-22 12:48:00
>   2013-07-22 13:26:00
>   2013-07-23 11:18:00
>   2013-07-23 11:48:00
>   2013-07-23 12:30:00
>   2013-07-23 13:12:00
>   2013-07-24 11:18:00
>   2013-07-24 11:42:00
>   2013-07-24 12:20:00
>   2013-07-24 12:52:00
>   2013-07-24 13:29:00

**Note: lstDays[i][j] is a datetime object.**

> lstDays = [ [/*datetime objects from a day i*/], [/*datetime objects from a day i+1*/], [/*datetime objects from a day i+2/*],  ... ]

And I am not worried with perfomance, a priori.

Hope that you can help me! (:

Comment: Show us the code you used to generate this, and what you want changed.

Comment: You have obviously made a concious decision there: "13:00, 13:00 and 13:05 form a group because they are close enough." Is that your limit? Five seconds? Or is it another one? Because you have not added 12:00 to that group, so it is not one hour.

Comment: My limit is 0 seconds. The minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can always resort to calculating the times into a list, then estimate the differences, and group those objects that are below that limit. All packed into a dictionary with the difference as the value and the the timestamps as keys. If this is not exactly what you need, I'm pretty sure it should be easy to select whatever result you need from it.

```
import numpy
import datetime
times_list = [object1.time(), object2(), ..., objectN()]
limit = 5 # limit of five seconds
groups = {}
for time in times_list:
    delta_times = numpy.asarray([(tt-time).total_seconds() for tt in times_list])
    whr = numpy.where(abs(delta_times) < limit)[0]
    similar = [str(times_list[ii]) for ii in whr]
    if len(similar) > 1:
        similar.sort()
        max_time = numpy.max(delta_times[whr])   # max? median? mean?
        groups[tuple(similar)] = max_time
```

Comment: Does this code just parse the string to a datetime object? It is not what I want :/

Comment: At the time of writting the answer I think there was no mention that they were already datetime.datetime objects. I don't know if I should remove the answer, for the moment there it is. I have completed one way of calculating the times at which your process is happening. But your problem is too wide open, how are you going to decide if the frequency is 1 day? what limits? what will your requirement be? Showing up every day within a limit? which limit?

Comment: What do you mean with limit = 5 ?

Comment: I mean that you might want to consider that 12:10:00 and 12:10:04 are the same hour in your experiment... But maybe 12:00:20 should not be in the same group. But your problem is stated in such a way that I am not sure how to tackle it, to be honest.

Comment: Indeed. I must to observe any difference between times. The algorithm that I am searching should be able to list all combination of times in different days ordered by the interval between the times or the smaller variation between times of different days. It's hard to explain in a few words.

Comment: So you would look at it like saying: "group all the images that have zero seconds difference, then group all the ones that have one second difference, and continue like that for all possible differences", is that it?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that. This way I can take a few to use on my experiment. Exaclty how you told me: I need all possible differences and what are the datetime objects that given to me this differences.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a histogram:

```
hours = [0] * 24
for object in objects:                # whatever your objects are
    # assuming object.date_time looks like '2013-07-18 10:55:00'
    hour = object.date_time[11:13]    # assuming the hour is in positions 11-12
    hours[int(hour)] += 1

for hour in xrange(24):
    print '%02d: %d' % (hour, hours[hour])
```

Comment: 1) What is the result of your code? 2) I don't know where are the hours positions, how could I assume that?

Comment: The result is a list of hours (0-23) and the number of objects that fall in each hour.  If your objects have an actual `datetime` value, use `hour = object.date_time.hour`

Comment: 1) Why did you consider just the 'hour' field? I think that minutes are important! 2) Is it considerating different days to each hour?

Comment: Because of your note: "I want to observe if a phenomenon occurs at the same hour in differents days."

Comment: I think the problem needs more explanation.  Please give a specific example of what you want to see.